# Scala: idiomatic Try-match and avoiding catching Throwable

Tags: scala, exception, throwable

In Scala, a typical use of pattern matching for exception handling (at least per sources like [this](https://alvinalexander.com/source-code/scala/scala-try-success-and-failure-example) and [this](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/26/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-6-error-handling-with-try.html)) looks like the following:

```
Try(...) match {
  case Success(_) => println("success")
  case Failure(exc) => println(s"caught: $exc")
}
```

However, that pattern also catches any non-`Exception` `Throwable`s thrown in the `try` block:

```
Try(throw new AssertionError("assertion error")) match {
  case Success(_) => println("success")
  case Failure(exc) => println(s"caught: $exc")
}

caught: java.lang.AssertionError: assertion error
```

In Java, at least, catching `Throwable` without a compelling reason to do so is generally considered to be an anti-pattern. ([This source](https://www.sumologic.com/blog/company/why-you-should-never-catch-throwable-in-scala/) offers the same counsel for Scala.)

One option to avoid silently catching `Throwable` is to catch it and re-throw it:

```
Try(throw new AssertionError("assertion error")) match {
  case Success(_) => println("success")
  case Failure(exc : Exception) => println(s"caught: $exc")
  case Failure(th) => throw th
}
```

It seems odd, though, that an extra re-throw is necessary to avoid catching non-`Exception` `Throwable`s (usually considered unrecoverable), and that letting such `Throwable`s escape, implicit in Java-style `try`/`catch` syntax, must be implemented explicitly.

Is there a more succinct / idiomatic syntax for using pattern-matching for exception-handling in Scala, while avoiding inadvertently catching `Throwable`?

Comment: FWIW, `Try` only catches [NonFatal](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/util/control/NonFatal$.html) throwables.

Comment: @hoyland Interesting point; if the answer to my original question is "no" (no such idiomatic syntax exists), maybe that explains why: the designers didn't consider it important to avoid catching `Throwable`, because they had already differentiated fatal vs. non-fatal `Throwable`s via the `NonFatal` extractor. (Though it seems unfortunate that the set of "fatal" `Throwable`s is non-extensible, in that case.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the `recover()` method takes a [PartialFunction](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/PartialFunction.html), it can be used to filter for the type of `Throwable` you want to handle. After that, you can let `get` unwrap the `Try` and retrieve a value if it was either a `Success` or a handled `Failure`, or it will re-throw if it's still a `Failure`, i.e. not handled by `recover()`.

```
val result = Try{
               //code block here
             }.recover{
               case exc:Exception => ... //should return same type as Success
             }.get //unwrap the Try, will throw if Throwable was not an Exception
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but it would seem to compel the use of another frowned-upon practice, calling `Option.get` (https://alvinalexander.com/scala/best-practice-option-some-none-pattern-scala-idioms#don-t-use-the-get-method-with-option). Is there a way to achieve the same effect without calling `get`? `getOrElse(throw ...)` appears to lose the original `Throwable`.

Comment: The reason `get` is discouraged is because it will throw if you try to `get` the wrong thing (`Option.None` or an unhandled `Try.Failure`), _but that's what you asked for_. The `get` will do the re-throw for you so you don't have to.